# Comparing an unknown type with string in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm completely new to the world of PHP and word press.

I need to compare a string with already defined function which returns some value but not `null`.

When i'm trying to `print` that function with an `echo` it prints some text but when I'm trying to get the type of the returning value using `get_type(function())` it returns `Null`.

And both known string and printed text are same, but still its not satisfying my if condition.

All I need to do is to compare a known string with the value returned from that method.

Edit :

The method which i'm trying to compare with a string is the_permalink() 
This method satisfies is_null() method but it prints the url at its calling.

Comment: Post exactly what your if statement is. Side note: var_dump() is a very useful function... Tells you type, value, and if its a string, the length.

Comment: This has nothing to do with WordPress. Use var_dump, and get the type of the variable, and cast the variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
$your_string = "something";
$returned_method_value = your_function();

if($your_string === $returned_method_value){ //=== for type check, if you don't want to know the type use ==
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: this is technically true but looks like the OP's problem has something unclear. Even loose comparison makes if condition return `false` so how strict comparison makes it return `true`?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try gettype()
without the underscore.

and if your checking for same or different types then you can do what bono said and go with

```
if( $type1 === $type2)
{
    //do something
}
```

also, posting some code to show us would be really helpful. We can't know for sure what is wrong unless we can see the code.

Answer (score 0):

as Anthory Saldana Jr. said, use `gettype()` instead of `get_type()`.

If I understood you correctly, this is what you're looking for:

```
function testFunction($input) {
    return $input;
}

echo gettype(testFunction(1))."<br>";
echo gettype(testFunction("a"))."<br>";

/* Prints:
 * integer
 * string
 */
```

Here's a phiddle to demonstrate: http://phiddle.net/3